# Eulerian and Hamiltonian cycles at the same time

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I want to ask if it's possible for a graph to have both Eulerian and Hamiltonian cycles at the same time? And what will happen with graph's connectivity? Could connectivity k(G) be k(G) > 1 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly it is possible. A triangle has both, as does $K_5$.  In fact, the complete graph on any odd number of vertices is an example.  Any cycle graph is another example.  The complete graph example shows the connectivity can be very high.